# Is this "string copy" unsafe?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, multidimensional-array, copy

Sorry for the format ahead of time. I have program that will take a user input string and sort them however I want. However, I've been seeing a lot of things about whether `strncopy` is safe or not along with other variations of `strcpy.` I decided to implement something similar, but I wanted to know if this is bad, or unsafe, programming. To make this simple, let's say the user inputted the string "Place on firm surface" onto `string[N]`

```
#define N 100

char string[N], stringSort[N][N], stringCopy[N][N], wordLength[4];
int wordCount = 4; //Just going by example string
```

Let's say the array of `string[N]` is sorted into `stringSort[N][N]` like this:

```
 0. Place\0 //Note: I'm not using strtok.
 1. on\0
 2. firm\0
 3. surface\0
```

The `wordLength[4]` array keeps track of the amount of characters in each index of `stringSort[N][N]`.

```
0. 6 //Note: I'm not using strnlen to determine the amount
1. 3
2. 5
3. 8
```

My loop for "string copying" is as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < wordLength[i]; j++)
        stringCopy[i][j] = stringSort[i][j];
```

So how bad/unsafe is my loop?

Comment: "*So how bad is my loop?*" it missed to copy each C-string's `0`-terminator.

Comment: BTW, there is no function called `strnlen()` in C.

Comment: If he keeps track of the string length seperately, he doesn't need the terminating null character. He then also has to e.g. print character-by-charcater or include length to print. So that is NO error (just a different implementation of the string type). `printf("%.*s", wordLength[i],stringCopy[i]);`

Comment: Are you sure? My program allows me to use `len =strnlen(string,N);` Also, I may have messed up on what is populated in the array. I can add \0 to each string and increase my character account, because I am using `puts()`

Comment: To *successfully* use `puts()` you *need* to `0`-terminate a `char`-array to become a C-string.

Comment: `strnlen()` probably is an extension, either GNU and/or POSIX.

Comment: I edited to include them. I was just wondering if my version of string copy is bad, or should I just stick to using `strncpy`? And I got `strnlen` from this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50ty2zh.aspx

Comment: `strncpy` should be safe, the issue is with `strcpy`. Personally I prefer to use standard functions over my own implemented version.

Comment: The one thing that I read about `strncpy` is that if you copy a truncated version of the string, it will not come with a NUL terminator. For example if I set strncpy to copy the first 3 letters of `Place\0`, it will only copy `Pla` and not end it with the NUL terminator.